# Not able to do Ejabberd Clustering

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have two Virtual Box with ubuntu  installed  i.e VM1 and VM2. Both of them are running the ejabbered and working fine.

The problem starts when i am trying to connect them in a cluster. below are the steps which i did

1) copied the .erlan.cookie file from VM1 to VM2

2) executef the below command in VM2
       ejabberdctl --no-timeout join_cluster 'ejabberd@Ubuntu-VB'

the error which i got is

Error : {no_ping, ejabberd@Ubuntu-VB}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make telnet connection from one to another to port 4369?

Comment: There is a typo in  `.erlan.cookie`. However, the issue is probably that your network is not correctly set up.

Comment: I have checked the telent using the local ip with port 4369 and its working fine.

$ telnet 10.1.20.144 4369

but when i do telnet using the ejabberd@Ubuntu-VB it says

telnet: could not resolve  ejabberd@Ubuntu-VB/4369 : Temporary failure in name resolution

Is i am missing anything??

Comment: @GopalSharma did you find the solution?